# Python mutiprocessing hangs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using python `multiprocessing` module in a program. The program looks like this:

```
processes = [Process(target=func1, args=(host,servers,q)) for x in range(1,i+1)]
```

The program is designed to create not more than 50 processes at a time, but it gets stuck after creating a random number of processes. Sometimes the program hangs after creating only 4 processes, sometimes at 9 processes and sometimes at 35 processes. 85% of the time, it gets stuck after creating 4 processes.

I have written another dummy program to test the maximum number of processes that can be created on my system. I can successfully create upto 1000 processes. But in case of this very program, it gets stuck at a random number of processes.

Note: The machine I am working on is a Ubuntu VM on top of a Windows host with Intel core i3 processor. I have allocated 4 CPU cores to the VM and 1Gig RAM.

Please suggest how can I resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at CPU utilization to make sure that the created processes aren't all taking all the CPU?

Comment: It seems that the processes connect to some remote host. Maybe the problem here is your network bandwidth?

Comment: That one line is not nearly enough of the code to tell what is going on.